# Показать элементы без ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть много div, и стоят они по 3 штуки в ряд. Изначально показывает 6 div, остальные скрываются. Я хочу добавить кнопку "показать еще" и при нажатии показывать следующие 6 div. Без ajax, все элементы уже на странице. Я не могу на стороне сервера обернуть каждые 6 div в какой-то родительский и таким образом показывать "каждые 6".

Answer (score 2):

https://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
$(function(){
  $("div").slice(0, 5).show();
  $("div").slice(6).hide();

  var start = 6;

  $("#showMore").click(function(){
    $("div").slice(start, start + 5).show();
    start = start + 6;
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо - работает!